# I am finding Raphael object using class name and animating, but not work at all

Tags: jquery, graphael

I got 2 no.of Circle, clicking big circle i am finding small circle using the class name and trying to animate the small circle, but not working at all.

But fadeId, fadeOut properites are working.

My function:

```
var paper = new Raphael('myPaper',500,500);
var circle = paper.circle(100,100,100).attr({'fill':'red'});
circle.node.setAttribute('class','red');
var text = paper.text(100,100,"test Text").attr({'fill':'#fff'});

var smallCircle = paper.circle(300,100,50).attr({'fill':'green'}).data('id','green');
smallCircle.node.setAttribute('class','green'); 

var newSet = paper.set();

newSet.push(circle,text);

newSet.attr({cursor:'pointer'}).data('id','oval');

$('.red').on('click',function () {   
    $('.green').animate({'cx':200},5000); //animation not working.
} )
```

​

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Amb9b/3/)

Comment: Your code doesn't have a `click` handler or use `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`?

Comment: i have no.of stuff to animate, so i decide to do by qQuery. fadeIn, and fadeOut works with same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to animate using Raphael you need to get the Raphael object for the element, rather than a jQuery object. To do that you need to get the `raphaelid` property from the element, and then use the [`getById`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getById) method of your canvas.

```
paper.getById($('.green')[0].raphaelid).animate({'cx': 200}, 5000);
```

---

If you have more than one element you can probably just loop through and animate each one.

```
var anim = Raphael.animation({'cx': 200}, 5000);
$('.green').each(function() {
    paper.getById(this.raphaelid).animate(anim);
}
```

Comment: You idea is ok. but i have no.of green classes in the page, i need to animate all.. is it possible?

Comment: You can probably just loop through all the elements and animate each one, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

`animate()` changes only the style attribute of an element, as far as I've seen.

However, you can hook into it to change other things, using the step function with animate: [jQuery animate of custom value (not a CSS property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154086/jquery-animate-of-custom-value-not-a-css-property)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call animate on a DOM SVG object. You will need to animate the raphael reference to the green circle, not the class.

```
newSet.click(function () {   
    smallCircle.animate({'cx':200},5000); //animation not working.
} )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Amb9b/8/